# How can I fix my route configuration to accept a second parameter?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, routes

I've modified my `Get()` endpoint to take another parameter, and it doesn't work anymore

```
public async Task<AjaxResponse> Get(long id, string appType)
{

}
```

This is the route config that I've added for the new parameter (if I don't add this, the request returns a 404):

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(  
    name: "GetUser",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{userId}/{appType}"
    );
```

Now requests for that endpoint, e.g.

```
/api/AccountApi/343434338361295/customer
```

end up at the default framework generated `Get()` endpoint:

```
public IEnumerable<string> Get()
{
    return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
}
```

What's wrong with my routing configuration, and what can I do to fix it?

For reference, my entire route configuration is as follows:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    //ASP.NET Web API Route Config
    routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

    routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "CreateOrLogin",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/CreateOrLogin/{appType}/{userId}"
        );

    routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "GetUser",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{userId}/{appType}"
        );

    routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "GetAdsForRetailer",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/GetAdsForRetailer/{userId}/{page}/{pageSize}"
        );

    routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "GetLatestAds",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/GetLatestAds/{userId}/{maxId}"//
        );

    routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "GetAd",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/GetAd/{userId}/{id}"//
        );

    routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "RegisterUser",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/RegisterUser/"//
        );

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot test this right now, but I think that the names you define in the route must match those in the Get method, i.e. instead of

```
routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{userId}/{appType}"
```

you should have

```
routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}/{appType}"
```

The route should match regardless of the names you give, but then the framework will probably try to use reflection to determine the method to call, and for that parameter names will be relevant.

Comment: agh! This was one of those try-to-refactor-quickly-on-the-train errors that I would never have spottted. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

There are two mistakes in your code:

Firstly, The name of your first parameter is not correct. Either use `userId` or update your route config as @paolo-tedesco said.

Apart from it, the types of parameters in Actions should always be **nullable**. You're supplying `long` for `userId`. Rest of your code is perfect. Just try using `long?` in the action.

```
public async Task<AjaxResponse> Get(long? userId, string appType)
{

}
```